# JSP execute a java class at first execution for setting up the backend

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I am currently coding a JSP application using IntelliJ Enterprise (latest version), Tomcat 9, MySQL Server and JDK 11 Server running on Windows 10.

Currently, I call the Java code doing the database setup from index.jsp. While that has been ok for getting started, I doubt that that is a good place for the final application.

However, I have failed to configure the web.xml file to call a Servlet or any other kind of Java class.

How can I configure the project in such a way, that when I first execute it, a Java class is run that does all the setup? There is really no point for the login page to run that code over and over again even if that code is able to determine that there is nothing to be done.

And another question about Java JSP:

If I were to declare a static variable within a Java class, would that variable be shared among all users using the web application?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As for the first question (configure the web-app on star), see https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/

Comment: As for the second, yes, a static field (variable) will be visible to all the users, but I would recommend being **VERY CAREFUL** using it, especially changing its value. Read this tutorial before you start: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html

Comment: Thanks, https://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/ seems to be what I am looking for. About the static variables: I guessed that static variables will be visible to other users which is why I have used none. But it is good to have it confirmed.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I just implemented the solution you linked and it works perfectly. I consider the question answered, though I can't accept a comment, or I think I can't. Thank you very much and good day.